# Spring Boot 406 "Not Acceptable"

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I am trying to build RESTful API using Spring Boot whose version is 2.0.5.RELEASE. Here's my controller:

```
// Just for test
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/login",method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestParam(name = "username") String username,
                                   @RequestParam(name = "password") String password) {

        ResponseEntity<RESTResponse> response = null;

        if(username.equals("123") && password.equals("123")){
            // success
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(RESTResponse.generateResponse(
                    null, "successful", "Log in successfully."), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            // failed
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(RESTResponse.generateResponse(
                    null, "failed", "Your username or password is incorrect."), HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```

And this is Spring MVC configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    /**
     * CORS configuration
     */
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(ALL)
                .allowedMethods(ALL)
                .allowedHeaders(ALL)
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }


}
```

The controller is supposed to response JSON data. I used Postman to test the controller. The controller could receive the request parameters and work properly but the Postman got a weird response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-09-16T05:55:14.860+0000",
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "message": "Could not find acceptable representation",
    "path": "/api/user/login"
}
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried

1. adding jackson
2. using @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)implements
3. Serializable

but was missing @Getter in dto.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `Accept: application/json` in postman header.

If above is done then try adding `consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` also in the method signature along with produces.

Comment: I've tried this and another problem appeared. Java got a WARN:`Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'username' is not present]`

Comment: yes this is happening because request doesn't contain request parameter. so ensure that you are adding parameter named username in postman request.

Answer (score 0):

you can implements **Filter** interface

and set the **header** with all method can be accepted

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter{


     static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);

     @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
              HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            logger.info(request.getRemoteAddr());
        }

        public void destroy() {}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have these jars and use Header `Accept: application/json` in postman headers

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the 406 Not Acceptable error too. After investigation, I found it's caused by returns invalid bean object from controller method.

I tried to return object of

- class `java.lang.Object` and
- class without any properties

They both produces HTTP 406 error.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a tricky problem to investigate.

406 means **Not Acceptable**

Now we were facing this while returning an error response. Our error pojo class was implementing `Response` interface

```
public class ErrorResponse implements Response {

  private final String error;

  private final ErrorDetails details;
}
```

And below is the code which was generating and returning the ResponseEntity response

```
private ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> buildErrorResponse(final String errorMessage, final ErrorDetails error,
      final HttpStatus httpStatus) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(httpStatus).body(ErrorResponse.builder().error(errorMessage).details(error).build());
  }
```

When we tested this in postman, we understood that the response is not complete and a valid json.

It was like below

```
data: { error: "Some Error", details : {}}
```

where as valid json response would look like below (because data is a wrapper from ResponseEntity which wraps the body)

```
{ error: "Some Error", details : {}}
```

So, the problem in our code was we were not setting the appropriate header. So the fixed code is like below. **.contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)** did the trick to convert it into a valid acceptable response

```
private ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> buildErrorResponse(final String errorMessage, final ErrorDetails error,
      final HttpStatus httpStatus) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(httpStatus).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).body(ErrorResponse.builder().error(errorMessage).details(error).build());
  }
```